# React - When we mouseover an element, how to select multiple elements except the we hover over?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, swiper.js

I am currently trying to replicate a function of the Netflix homepage:

We have several rows of movies. When we don't mouseover any movie, the movie images stay normal. But when we hover over a movie, the current image scales up and all the other ones in this row to get their opacity reduced. When we "onMouseOut" the row, everything gets back to normal

I am currently wondering how to implement that into an onMouseOver function. If anyone has an idea, that'd very helpful.

PS: I also use Swiper JS.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: add sample https://codesandbox.io/ for help you is better

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be to add a class to that element during the onMouseOver event. This way you can easily select what elements you would like to stylize.
You could also add a class name to the container so that you could select all elements without selected class or without a hover. Please try the one below, it seems to be the simplest:

```
.container:hover > .item:not(:hover) { 
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Please see the codepen below:

https://codepen.io/damianbartosik/pen/JjrzrZd